# How to count the number of times a "number" appears in string using php?

Tags: php, html, preg-match

I am trying to count how many times number appears in a string. For example, in the string "rt_876_io_542_po_367" there are three numbers and in the string "tr_766_ 756" there are two numbers. How do I do this with PHP?? I tried the following code:

```
        $str="RT_657_YT_89";
        $key=preg_match_all('!/_[0-9]_/!',$str);
        echo $key;
```

but it echos "0"!! please help

Comment: You tagged this with `preg_match`, so I'm assuming you at least know that you need to use a regex. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Will the numbers be always surrounded by an `_`?

Comment: Extract the numbers from string and count the `preg_match`'s result.

Comment: @iainn No need to, people will answer. Which doesn't help them really - teach a person to fish...

Comment: @James That's a wrong intention. People spoonfed with answers will never learn. **Edit:** Sorry man. Good one. Didn't know you were writing it. Don't submit a comment without finishing it.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Sometimes, the Enter key is just too close to the other keys.

Comment: @MrLister LoL...

Comment: You can `$numbers = count(array_filter(explode('_', $str), function($v){return ctype_digit($v);}));`

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be accomplished with a regular expression.

```
function countDigits( $str )
{
    return preg_match_all( "/[0-9]/", $str );
}
```

The function will return the amount of times the pattern was found, which in this case is any digit.

Comment: @PraveenKumar The return value of `preg_match_all` *is* the count

Comment: @iainn Thanks. `:)` LoL. I forgot.